# Ektron 8.6 - Appending Metadata Tags into the Head tags of a page

Tags: .net, ektron

I am trying to automatically append some Metadata onto a page in Ektron dynamically.

I have created a Metadata item in the settings area of Ektron called "Twitter Card" which has been set to a text property.

As twitter card Metatags are different they are reliant at page level so by adding this by the use of a Metadata option in the page settings seems the only possibe solution.

I have added the following into the Head section of my Master Template.

```
asp:Literal ID="SetTwitterCard" runat="server"
```

And I have also added this into the .cs part of the page but I'm having no success

```
protected void SetTwitterCard ()
{
  HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
  meta.Name = "TwitterCard";
  meta.Content = this.CurrentPage.GetMetaDataValue(Resources.Metadata.TwitterCard);
  this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a literal defined on your ASPX page's front end then you won't need to programmatically add any controls to `Page.Header.Controls`.  Choose one method or the other.

#### Common Code

First, Add this code to your page class. It loads the `ContentData` with its metadata from the primary content block if present (`id` query string parameter) and falls back on the form block if present (`ekfrm` query string parameter) and finally falls back on the PageBuilder page layout if present (`pageid` query string parameter). Both **option 1** and **option 2** require all of this "common code" to be present in your page class in order to function.

```cs
private bool _isContentLoaded;
private Ektron.Cms.ContentData _content;

private string GetMetadataFromPrimaryContent(string metadataName)
{
    EnsureContentIsLoadedFromEktron();

    if (_content == null || _content.MetaData == null) return null;

    var data = _content.MetaData.FirstOrDefault(md => md.Name == metadataName);
    return data == null ? null : data.Text;
}

private void EnsureContentIsLoadedFromEktron()
{
    if (_isContentLoaded) return;

    _isContentLoaded = true;
    var cm = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content.ContentManager();

    long id;
    long.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out id);

    if (id > 0)
        _content = cm.GetItem(id, true);

    if (_content != null) return;

    long.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ekfrm"], out id);
    if (id > 0)
        _content = cm.GetItem(id, true);

    if (_content != null) return;

    // if no content is returned and we have a page id,
    // try getting that content block, since PageBuilder
    // pages can have metadata on them.
    long.TryParse(Request.QueryString["pageid"], out id);
    if (id > 0)
        _content = cm.GetItem(id, true);
}
```

#### Option 1:  Using a literal.

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltlTwitterCard" runat="server" />
```

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var metadataValue = GetMetadataFromPrimaryContent("TwitterCard");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metadataValue))
        ltlTwitterCard.Text = "<meta name=\"TwitterCard\" content=\""
                                + metadataValue
                                + "\" >";
}
```

#### Option 2: Programmatically add the control to the Head.

If using this route, please note the following from [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/specifying-the-title-meta-tags-and-other-html-headers-in-the-master-page-cs):

> Notice that the `<head>` element contains a `runat="server"`
>   attribute, which indicates that it is a server control (rather than
>   static HTML).

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var meta = new HtmlMeta
    {
        Name = "TwitterCard",
        Content = GetMetadataFromPrimaryContent("TwitterCard") ?? ""
    };

    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
}
```

Comment: Good response. I would add a querystring check for "ekfrm" - the querystring param for Ektron's HTML Forms. I actually create a third method / property for returning the ID of the current page, looking first for id, then ekfrm, then pageid, in that order.

Comment: Good points, @egandalf!  I've updated my answer to include a fall back on "ekfrm" before finally falling back on pageid. I've used a method for just returning the id before, and that works really well. One thing I like about this approach, however, is that in the case where you're using a Page Layout as a template (hence the url has both "id" and "pageid") you can fall back on the page layout's metadata in the event that a non-existent content id is specified. Ex: ?id=75&pageid=102 -> content id 75 is deleted, I can show a "not found" message but still load metadata from the page layout.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, much appreciated,


I have tried Option 1 and when I hover over the words - GetMetadataFromPrimaryContent and Content I get "The name GetMetadataFromPrimaryContent does not exist in the current context.

I will try the other options to see if they work.

Comment: I do already have this code which appends the Page Title and Description from the page metadata

protected void SetPageMeta()
{
if (this.CurrentPage != null)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CurrentPage.GetMetaDataValue(Resources.Metadata.PageTitle)))
{
PageTitle.Text = this.CurrentPage.GetMetaDataValue(Resources.Metadata.PageTitle) + " | my site ";
 }
else
{
PageTitle.Text = CurrentPage.Title + " | my site ";
}
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "description";
meta.Content =this.CurrentPage.GetMetaDataValue(Resources.Metadata.PageDescription);
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
}
}

Comment: @DaveKane - the method "GetMetadataFromPrimaryContent" exists in the "common code" section.  The variable "content" is a type-o and should be "metadataValue". I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DaveKane - you'll have to dig into your workarea a bit... this code works, but it assumes that (A) the metadata field exists, (B) the name in the code (TwitterCard in the case above) is spelled correctly with exact capitalization, and (C) that the metadata field has been applied to the particular content block you are trying to access.  Once you have verified all that, if it still isn't working then step through the code - particularly the methods in the common code section of my answer, and verify that the Ektron API is returning a valid ContentData object with Metadata.

Comment: Ok, thanks - this is what I have set up - I have added links to images too to explain in detail.

1. 'TwitterCard' Metadata Definition in the work area as a 'HTML Tag' Type (under the settings area).
http://bit.ly/1mFLPcj

2. I have assigned this Metadata Type at folder level so all pages can use it.

I think the main problem is that when I add either option 1 or 2 - I get a red line underneath the 'GetMetadataFromPrimaryContent' part.
http://bit.ly/1pMlMnr

Comment: @DaveKane - thanks, I think we're getting close. Regardless of which option you choose from my answer, you'll need to also copy in the code from the "common code" section to the same Page class in which you're adding to the Page_Load event. I'll update the text in my answer so it's a little more clear.

Comment: Just tried this and now it 'Reds' out the 'newContentManager()' Part ----  Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content.ContentManager cm = new ContentManager();

See screenshot http://bit.ly/1mGrJ1C

Comment: @DaveKane - that's a pretty easy fix if you look at the error message. You have a class in your solution called ContentManager. I will update my answer to be a little more explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far with this but I have tried adding the updated code and tried both Option 1 and 2 with the Common code and I still get an error page...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `this.CurrentPage.GetMetaDataValue(Resources.Metadata.TwitterCard)` works, the following is how I typically have metadata added on my masterpage(s).  It may work in your case as well.

Front end:

```
<meta id="metaTwitterCard" runat="server" name="TwitterCard" content=""/>
```

Back end:

```
    protected void SetTwitterCard ()
    {
      /*HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
      meta.Name = "TwitterCard";
      meta.Content = this.CurrentPage.GetMetaDataValue(Resources.Metadata.TwitterCard);
      this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);*/

      // Fill in "TwitterCard" content.
      metaTwitterCard.Content = this.CurrentPage.GetMetaDataValue(Resources.Metadata.TwitterCard);
      // Hide meta tag if content invalid or unavailable.
      metaTwitterCard.Visible = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(metaTwitterCard.Content);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing this solution however I get a 'Red' Error line underneath the 'TwitterCard' Text in this line 
 metaTwitterCard.Content = this.CurrentPage.GetMetaDataValue(Resources.Metadata.TwitterCard);

The error message reads - Resources.Metadata Does not contain a definition for TwitterCard.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure. Right-click on .Metadata. from that line in the code and click on "Go To Definition" in the context menu that pops up.  That will bring you to wherever Resources.Metadata is defined.  In there you should have .TwitterCard defined if you don't already.  I'm thinking these are just accessors to your Ektron metadata definition names as strings.

Comment: Thanks for that, it appears that I need to add the new metadata definition into that area however its all encrypted within a DLL file, the Metadata file is locked..

Comment: OK, just another guess: You might have a resource file (.resx) called Metadata that holds your metadata definition names.  Common places for these are in the site's App_GlobalResources and App_LocalResources folders if they exist.  If all else fails, try just passing "Twitter Card" into the this.CurrentPage.GetMetaDataValue( method to see if things work ok.